# How to use the User built in model as a default value of another form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am working on a project dealing with the built-in User model. I have a class that showed me how to use the User model...Registering, Login/Logout, Dashboard, Being able to update a user's profile, and Deleting an account. But I can't get it to click on using the logged-in User in other ways.

The goal of the app is to

1. A logged-in user can 'create' a deck, and the 'User' field is auto-set to the logged-in user. **UPDATE** Currently, the form won't save anything unless it's filled in from the admin panel.

**views.py**

```
def my_decks(request):
    deck_list = Deck.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)

    if request.method == "POST":
        deck = DeckForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        deck.user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
        if deck.is_valid():
            deck.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/my-decks')
    else:
        deck = DeckForm()

    context = {'deck': deck, 'deck_list': deck_list, 'user': user}
    return render(request, 'gametracker_app/my-decks.html', context=context)


---

# All below was from the class and works

def register(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            current_user = form.save(commit=False)
            form.save()
            profile = Profile.objects.create(user=current_user)
            return redirect('my-login')
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'gametracker_app/register.html', context=context)


def my_login(request):
    form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')

            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                auth.login(request, user)
                return redirect('dashboard')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Invalid Login')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'gametracker_app/my-login.html', context=context)


def user_logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return redirect('')


def dashboard(request):
    profile_pic = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    context = {'profilePic': profile_pic}
    return render(request, 'gametracker_app/dashboard.html', context=context)


def profile_management(request):
    # prepopulated fields
    user_form = UpdateUserForm(instance=request.user)
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    profile_form = UpdateProfilePicForm(instance=profile)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UpdateUserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = UpdateProfilePicForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            return redirect('dashboard')
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile_form.save()
            return redirect('dashboard')

    context = {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form}
    return render(request, 'gametracker_app/profile-management.html', context=context)


def delete_account(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        delete_user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
        delete_user.delete()
        return redirect("")

    return render(request, 'gametracker_app/delete-account.html')
```

**forms.py**

```
class DeckForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Deck
        fields = {'deck', 'is_cedh'}


---

# All below was from the class and works

class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = {'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', }


class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput())
    password = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput())


class UpdateUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = None

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = {'username', 'email'}
        exclude = {'password1', 'password2'}


# Updating profile picture
class UpdateProfilePicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    profile_pic = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control-file'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = {'profile_pic'}
```

**models.py**

```
class Deck(models.Model):
    deck = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    is_cedh = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User,
                             max_length=10,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.deck

---

# All below was from the class and works

class Profile(models.Model):
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True,
                                    blank=True,
                                    default='images/Default.png',
                                    upload_to='images/')

    user = models.ForeignKey(User,
                             max_length=10,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

**my-decks.html**

```
  <div class="container bg-white shadow-md p-5 form-layout">

    {% if deck_name.count == 0 %}
      <h3 class="">Looks like you don't have any decks. Add one below</h3>
    {% else %}
      <h3 class="">Your Decks</h3>
    {% endif %}

    {% for foo in deck_list %}
      <p class="">{{ foo }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

    <br>
    <br>
    <h3 class="">Add New Deck</h3>
    <form action=""
          method="POST"
          autocomplete="off">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ deck.is_cedh }}
      {{ deck.deck }}
      <br>
      <input class="btn btn-primary"
             type="submit"
             name=""
             value="Submit">
      <br>
    </form>
  </div>
```